# jQuery UI Autocomplete not working with Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I would like to use jQuery UI Autocomplete on Wordpress but for some reason it is not working.

Anyway, I'll show you what I have already:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="db-search" id="db-search" autocomplete="off" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#db-search').autocomplete({ 
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:"/wp-content/themes/your-click/autocomplete.php",
      data: { autocomplete: 'true' },
    });
      }
    }, { minLength: 1 });
```

**PHP** (autocomplete.php)

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $string = wpdb::_real_escape( $_GET['term'] );
    $get_results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM yc_customers WHERE website LIKE $string ORDER BY website ASC");

    $json[] = '';
    foreach ($get_results as $get_result) {
        array_push($json, $get_result->website);
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
    flush;
?>
```

I am not getting any errors when testing it with chrome. So I don't know what's wrong with my code but there must be something wrong with the PHP, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Update

`php` at Question appear to be expecting "GET" request `$_GET['term']` ? Try subsituting `$string = wpdb::_real_escape( $_POST['autocomplete'] );` for `$string = wpdb::_real_escape( $_GET['term'] );`

See [Autocomplete - Remote JSONP datsource - viewsource](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

---

`.autocomplete()` expects `response(Array)` , also appear to be trailing comma `,` at `data: { autocomplete: 'true' },`

Try

```
$('#db-search').autocomplete({ 
    source: function (request, response) {
              // input query 
              var term = request.term;
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"/wp-content/themes/your-click/autocomplete.php",
                // "POST" `term` to server
                data: { autocomplete: term }
              }).then(function(data) {
                response(data)
              }, function error(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
              });
      }
    },
    minLength: 1 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, now I am getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '3' in [""]. It shows me that this error is coming from jquery.min.js. Also it is saying that response(data) (which is in your code) is an anonymous function.

Comment: Try opening `console` click  "Network" -> "Response" . Is response sent from server ? Is `data` returned from `$.post()` an array containing empty string `[""]` ?

Comment: When I click on Network, there is no so-called "Response". I was testing it with Chrome and Firefox. Only thing I see is that a post has been successfully sent to autocomplete.php but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @RezaSaadati See updated post.  Noticed `php` at Question appear to be expecting "GET" request `$_GET['term']` ? Try subsituting `$string = wpdb::_real_escape( $_POST['autocomplete'] );` for `$string = wpdb::_real_escape( $_GET['term'] );`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I see "Response" now. It is returning [""]. I tried replacing your code but it didn't help. I also tried this: `$string = $_GET['term'];` and `$string = $_POST['autocomplete'];` but it is still saying that `response(data)` is an anonymous function.

Comment: @RezaSaadati Does `$json` contain items at `php` ? If `minLength` set at `1` , would there be any returned values from database query of `1` character ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78617/discussion-between-reza-saadati-and-guest271314).